# Visual basic Chart

Tags: vb.net, windows, forms

I am moving a class and vb windows form to another project where I want to transfer the chart from project 2 to project 1. The class I am trying to uses the System.Windows.DataVisualization.Chart. I enabled both

```
System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting

System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting
```

,and they are not showing up in the toolbox for my to drag to my project but they show up in the project I want to move.
I also check the references and all references are the same between projects.

I have all the chart toolbox elements enabled but none of them are showing up.

Changed the frameworks to point to the same target framework and the chart did show up in the toolbox but when I insert it into the window it will not show up

Comment: Visual Basic or VBA? Please remove wrong tag and tag it correctly. `System.Windows.DataVisualization.Chart` looks like VB

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio Express 2010 or a different year or maybe Pro?

Comment: I am using Visual Basic 2012 Professional.

Comment: Are they both targeting the same framework version?

Comment: No one is using 3.5 and the other 4.5